# Intuitive interpretation of a Markov Chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

I have a graph representing scores of various players of a game against each other in match-ups of 2 players. It is a game where players are in "attacking" and "defending" positions. The game is such that some players are good at "attacking" others, but may be bad at "defending" against the same opponent.

Every player has played against every other player in both attacking and defending position. So we have a fully connected directed graph.

I convert it into a Markov Chain by dividing each entry of each row by the sum of the entries in the row (still not clear if this is necessary, or if there's a simpler way to do it).

I then compute the left eigenvector of said matrix for eigenvalue 1 and normalize. I am told this is to be interpreted as a "stationary distribution" of the Markov Chain.

My question is this: Can I interpret the resulting vector as a list of "the best players", represented by different nodes? Eg lower/higher means more/less skilled?

Comment: For me there is a gap in the explanation between the 4th and 5th paragraphs when we go from a graph, called 'it' in parag 5, to a matrix.So the meaning of the matrix is unclear. The 'eigen' part and the 'stationalry' part are fine. Possible to give an example, showing motivational connections?

Comment: Sorry, it seems I abstracted way too much. I unabstracted while trying not to go into excessive details about the game, and in the process I may have answered my own question -__-

Comment: I mean, intuitively it makes sense because the markov chain represents empirically derived probabilities of winning, so then does the standing distribution represent which would be most likely to win if they were matched up at random repeatedly? Again I may have just answered my own question...